# Angular ui-router : Parent & Child Views

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to build a site with the following structure header-view, main-view, footer-view .
So I defined a root route which contains the header & footer. Children of root will be all my sites.Within these sites I will have more nested views.

In the code below it does show the header, but not the footer & the main view. As soon as I remove the parent inheritance, it shows the main view but not the header & the footer.

HTML

```
<body ng-app="App">
    <header ui-view="header"></header>
    <main ui-view></ui-view>
    <footer ui-view="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

JS

```
   module.config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
      $stateProvider
        .state('root', {
          abstract: true,
          views: {
            '@': {
                controller: 'RootCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'rootCtrl'
            },
            'header@': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/header/header.html',
                controller: 'HeaderCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'headerCtrl'
            },
            'footer@': {
                templateUrl: 'modules/footer/footer.html',
                controller: 'FooterCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'footerCtrl'
                }
           }
        })
        .state('root.home',{
            parent:'root',
            url:'',
            templateUrl:'modules/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs:'homeCtrl'
        });
    });
```

Comment: could you create raw working jsfiddle/plunkr, so we can play around.? On a first look, I would remove  'abstract : true' and 'parent:root' as it's already done via path definitions, next specify @root for header and footer.anyway sample is better

Comment: I didn't understand the last sentence. Here is a plunkr:
http://embed.plnkr.co/0U5vQxhrjlYPhkRPZ1mI/preview

Comment: I don't know if you can chain the stateprovider. I guess you have to insert   $stateProvider before each .state but still this isnot changing anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a link to [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/iNGHpplIDn03vdmTe72K?p=preview).

The `UI-Router` logic how to find a target/anchor for a view is: **always try insert `child` into `parent`**. If not possible, then use absolute naming. see:

#### [View Names - Relative vs. Absolute Names](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views#view-names---relative-vs-absolute-names)

So what I changed, is, that the parent unnamed view is now containing a target/anchor for a child - unnamed view `<ui-view />`:

```
.state('root', {
  abstract: true,
  views: {
    '@': {
        template: '<ui-view />', // NEW line, with a target for a child
        controller: 'RootCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'rootCtrl'
    },
    ....
```

Also, because we say, that the default url is

```
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
```

we have to have such state:

```
.state('root.home',{
    parent:'root',
    url:'/home', // this is the otherwise, to have something on a start up
```

Check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iNGHpplIDn03vdmTe72K?p=preview)

Another approach with a [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/phQeiI50S4hEdfJoCEEq?p=preview), could be to target the root view in the child:

```
.state('root.home',{
    parent:'root',
    url:'/home',
    views: {
      '@': {
      templateUrl:'home.html',
      controller: 'HomeController',
      controllerAs:'homeCtrl'
      }
    },
```

In this case, the parent state does not have to have `<ui-view />` - we target root, but we won't be inheriting anything... Why is that? See this link:

#### [Scope Inheritance by View Hierarchy Only](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#scope-inheritance-by-view-hierarchy-only)

Comment: Kohler, I'm trying with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37607364/angular-routing-to-child-child-from-different-parents. if you can help me :)

Comment: @cracker your issue seems to be too abstract. If you can create some plunker (broken one) I am ready to assist. But in general... if you know the target state name ("parent.child1.child") and parmas {parentid:x, childid:y} ... it should not be an issue..