# Angular Routing to Child - Child from different parents

Tags: angularjs, typescript, routes

I am using typescript for routing in angular but facing some issue with routing. Flow seems to be:

[image]

What I actually want to do is route through Child which is the part of Child2 with Id to Child of Child1

but it's not displaying the page.

All the route of Child1 for insert, update resides in Child1 and routes for Child2 itself and i want to go to edit page of child which is part of Child1 from Child of Child2.

Any Help is Appreciated!

Comment: What router are you using? How are you setting up your routes? How are you trying to redirect from Child2/child to Child1/child?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long search, i have found one solution which let me redirect to parent from child directly.

What i was using is TypeScript $routeConfig to route between component as below

```
this.$routeConfig = [
{ path: '/', name: 'listofitemsanddetails', component: 'myitemlist', useAsDefault: true },
{ path: '/:id/info', name: 'itemdetails', component: 'listitenmdetail' }];
```

But it won't allow me to redirect to `itemdetails` from child of another component then i tried using `$router.parent.navigate(['listofitems']);` which resides in `grandparent` of my application and then i have added  some logic of redict to `itemdetails` in default route (`listofitems`) of grandparent component which redirects to `listofitemsanddetails` component as default.