# UI router cannot resolve state error message

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I am working on angular application at the moment, using ui-router and I am getting the following error message.

> Error: Could not resolve 'static.about' from state 'static'

and I am not sure why. What I am wanting to achieve is to have 2 sections to my application, the static section, homepage, about, login, register and the app side which would things like dashboards, user profiles etc I thought I would need to set up my ui-router like this,

```
app
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
// any unknown URLS go to 404
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/404');
// no route goes to index
$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');
// use a state provider for routing
$stateProvider
    .state('static', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: '',
        views : {
            header : {
                templateUrl : 'app/components/shared/header.html'
            },
            main: {
                templateUrl : 'app/components/home/views/home.view.html' 
            }
        }
    })
    .state('static.about', {
        // we'll add another state soon
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'app/components/about/views/about.view.html',
    })
    .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: ''
    })
    .state('app.dashboard', {
        url: 'app/dashboard',
        templateUrl : '',
    })        
}]);
```

However this returns the error already mentioned. The reason I am wanting to set it up like this that the 2 sides to application also have very different layouts, so I figured that I should be able push different layouts into my ?

The biggest problem I am having however is the error, and secondly the links being generated, when I click on about it should go to /about, however it is going to /home/about.

All I am wanting to achieve in the early stages is for my "static" pages to share a nav and have interchangeable main section, and for "app" pages to have a completly new layout/parent template

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `parent` property on the children views.

```
.state('static.about', {
    url         : '/about',
    templateUrl : 'app/components/about/views/about.view.html',
    parent      : 'static'
})
```

Also check the answer to this question [Angular ui-router : Parent & Child Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27312840/angular-ui-router-parent-child-views).

I guess that when you do `$state.go(static.about)` it just goes to `homepage` since you are doing an `otherwise` or something similar.

Like : `$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');`

`Angular-Ui-Router` resolves the main `route` when something isn't okay.

Also pay attention to the extra `,` you are adding at the end of `templateUrl`.

Answer (score 0):

The above construction of states is ok. I created a [plunker to demonstrate it here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bXqKzyjz9jOsk4nKAeF8?p=preview)

In a root state *'static'* we just do not use templateUrl.. it would be skipped anyhow, because we do define **`views : {}`**

```
  .state('static', {
      url: '/home',
      // we want to have views : {} so avoid this shorthand template
      // templateUrl: '',
      views: {
        header: {
          templateUrl : 'app/components/shared/header.html',
        },
        main: {
          templateUrl : 'app/components/home/views/home.view.html',
        }
      }
    })
```

And a child state *'static.about'* can use **`'^'`** leading sign, to reset its url from root

```
    .state('static.about', {
      // here we use a switch to inform - this url starts from root
      //url: '/about',
      url: '^/about',
      templateUrl: 'app/components/about/views/about.view.html',
    })
```

And with these calls, all is working

```
<a ui-sref="static">
<a ui-sref="static.about">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bXqKzyjz9jOsk4nKAeF8?p=preview)

The Error message:

> Error: Could not resolve 'static.about' from state 'static'

Usually happens, if we have a typoe in state definition (or calling side). But that is not the issue. Or if we omit to load definition file...

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that, you don't want to define a completely new UI when going to static.about but use the header from static.

1. Remove the templateUrl from static.about
2. Add a property view that should be an object with a property called "main@static" and the value should be another object with your templateUrl.

More info: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views